# jmeter how to capture an url encoding value and sending it without re-encoding

Tags: jmeter

I'm having problems with a value who is already in url encoding, I capture it fine but when I'm goin to send it, the value is re-encoded...
This is the value:

```
_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aes type="text/javascript">
```

I'm using a RegEx to capture:

```
Reference name: RSM
Regular Expression: _TSM_CombinedScripts_=(.+?)" type="text/javascript">
```

And I put a BSF Sampler to see the captured value, and is fine.

But when I put the value in the fields that send it to the server in a post method (rsmScriptManager_TSM=${RSM})the value is re recoded again like this:

```
rsmScriptManager_TSM=%253b%253bSystem.Web.Extensions%252c%2BVersion%253d4.0.0.0%252c%2BCulture%253dneutral%252c%2BPublicKeyToken%253d31bf3856ad364e35%253aes
```

Note that, for example at the begining of the chain is:

```
 %253b%253bSystem.Web.Extensions
```

The literal value is :

```
;;System.Web.Extensions
```

The ";;" are url encoding as %3b%3b, and exactly like that I'm capturing it, but when is send it to the server is re encoding the "%" with the %25

([HTML URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp))

And istead of %3b%3b value is sending %253b%253:

```
%253b%253bSystem.Web.Extensions
```

And is doing the same for other characters like "+"

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you don't have `Encode?` box ticked for the extracted request parameter

[image: Decode]

There is also [__urldecode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urldecode) function which can be helpful.

For more information on __urldecode and other useful JMeter functions check out [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series